# selenium js wait for iframe to fully load

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have a page that loads an iframe, inside the iframe a spinner spins (overlay over the fields)

I am using selenium to switch to the iframe,

```
  return this.driver.wait(function() {
    return self.webdriver.until.ableToSwitchToFrame(self.driver.findElement(self.page.loginIframe.selector))
  }, this.config.driver.defaultTimeout);
```

then calling  `this.driver.switchTo().frame(0);` once the above returns true

however I need to wait until the spinner is gone and that the input fields are ready for input.

If I use a `driver.sleep` I am able to get the data inputted correctly, but when I try to .elementIsVisible, it tries straight away to input data and fails.

code to attempt a login:

```
var self = this;
this.waitForPageLoad().then(function pageLoaded() {
    console.log("page loaded");
    self.switchToIframe().then(function switchedToIframe() {
      console.log("switched to iframe");
      // THIS FIXES the issue, but I do not want a random sleep self.driver.sleep(10000);
      self.waitForIframeLoad().then(function iframeLoaded() {
        console.log("iframe loaded!");            
        self.setUserName(self.config.user.userName);//FAILS HERE
      });
    });
});
```

code that throws error:

```
Login.prototype.waitForIframeLoad = function() {
  var self = this;
  //console.log(self.webdriver.until);
  return this.driver.wait(function() {
    return self.webdriver.until.elementIsVisible(self.driver.findElement(self.page.usernameInputField.selector))
  }, this.config.driver.defaultTimeout);
};
```

error message: `NoSuchElementError: no such element`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got past this checking first if it is present, the dom of the iframe did not load straight away which was causing the error.

```js
Login.prototype.waitForIframeLoad = function() {
  var self = this;
  console.log(self.webdriver.until);
  var deferred = this.webdriver.promise.defer();
  this.driver.wait(function(){
    //wait for the element to be present
    return self.driver.isElementPresent(self.page.usernameInputField.selector);
  }).then(function(){
    // then check if it is visibile
    return self.driver.wait(self.webdriver.until.elementIsVisible(self.driver.findElement(self.page.usernameInputField.selector)));
  }).then(deferred.fulfill);
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

edit: forgot the second wait function